# Error when POST file multipart/form-data (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, fetch-api

I got an error every time when trying to POST data to the API.
**Request:**

```
changeUserAvatar(authParam, file) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  //file is actually new FileReader.readAsDataURL(myId.files[0]);
  formData.append('profile_image', file);

  fetch(BASE_URL + 'profile-image', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization': authParam
    },
    body: formData
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((response) => {
    debugger;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

**Error**: profile_image can not be blank (422).

But it's not blank!

**Request payload**:
[image]

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved at GutHub: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/505

I just had to leave `Header` without pointing any `Content-Type` manually.